# C continious allocation with different type

Tags: c, memory, allocation

I need to recreate a memory organizer using the fisrt-fit model : 
We allocate continuous memory and then we need to allocate precise block. 
We know with the help of a linked list which block is free.

The problem is that i need to store the linked list inside our big continuous memory and whenever i try to do it on the the middle of the bloc i got a segment core dump.

Here is my code :

```
  char mem_heap[HEAP_SIZE]; //allocated the big continuous memory block
  //HEAP_SIZE = 1<<20 

  typedef struct fb1 {   //The linked list structure
     size_t size ;
     struct fb *next ;
  }fb ,*pfb;

  pfb liste ; // a pointer to the linked list

  void mem_init(){  // function which initialize the linked list

      pfb newlist = (pfb) mem_heap ;

      newlist->next = NULL ; 
      newlist->size = HEAP_SIZE  ;
      liste = newlist ;   
    }


//test of a function which try to free a block of memory located at the 
// memory address zone and of size size. 
void mem_free(void *zone, size_t size){

  pfb tmp = (pfb) zone ; 
  tmp->size = size ;
  tmp->next = liste ;

}
```

the line tmp->size produce a segment core dump error. 
I don't know why it is working at initialization and not here

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. Why don't you declare `mem_heap` with the correct type?

Comment: *Run it under a debugger*. We have idea how `mem_free` is being called, and more specifically what you're passing it when calling it. Thus we have no way of knowing for sure what is causing the failure, and can provide little more than wild guesses.

Comment: To begin with, change `char mem_heap[HEAP_SIZE]` to `fb mem_heap[HEAP_SIZE/sizeof(fb)]`.

Comment: With `pfb newlist = (pfb) mem_heap`, the result of any attempt to access memory via `newlist` is generally undetermined. It could lead to an unaligned load/store operation, the result of which is a segmentation fault at best, and unexpected data in memory at worst. "At best" - because you immediately become aware of the problem. "At worst" - because the problem will eventually emerge at a later point in the execution of your program, and you will have a very hard time tracing it backwards).

Comment: On second reading: Never `typedef` pointers! That inhibits qualifier-correct code (unless you pollute the namespace) and is error-prone.